# Error with substring in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering if XSLT has the option to delete the content of an element if the chars are more than 200. Below I make use of all the content element.

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: runtime error: file stylesheet.xslt line 42 element apply-templates in index.php on line 20

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: The 'select' expression did not evaluate to a node set. in index.php on line 20

```
<xsl:template match="a:content | description">
  <c>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="substring('node() | @*', 1, 200)" />
  </c>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Mmm... I don't quite follow what you're doing, but I would approach it by checking the string length inside an if block.. maybe your solution is slicker (as I said, I don't quite understand it)...

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="substring('node() | @*', 1, 200)" />

This is probably your problem. This will return a string which in turn will not evaluate to some node. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: @FailedDev The node is the content | description. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @mtopia Yeah sorry. Without a sample .xml is hard to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @FailedDev this is a sample of my feed http://codepad.org/AaQk4dqU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates select="substring('node() | @*', 1, 200)" />
> ```

**The Xpath expression specified in the `select` attribute above, is of type `xs:string`**.

However, in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 templates can only be applied on nodes -- not on strings. This is why you get the reported error message.

**It seems to me that what you most probably want is**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 200)" />
```